# Texture Brush (Drawing Application ) Using Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am trying to implement a metal-backed drawing application where brushstrokes are drawn on an MTKView by textured square repeatedly along a finger position. 
[image]

I am drawing this with alpha 0.2. When the squares are overlapped the color is added. How can I draw with alpha 0.2.

Comment: What if you were to just encode your draw calls within a single stroke's render encoder with alpha = 1, but blend onto previous strokes with the correct alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to draw the brush squares to a separate texture, initially cleared to transparent, without blending. Then draw that whole texture to your view with blending.

If you draw the brush squares directly to the view, then they will accumulate. After you draw square 1, it's part of the image. Metal can no longer distinguish it from anything else that was already there. So, when you draw square 2 overlapping it, it will blend with what's already there, including square 1.

Comment: When the brush stroke crosses there has to be blending. If we disable blending we cannot expect those meeting points. In Normal drawing applications when two strokes crosses there has to be blending https://imgur.com/gallery/UpXNfe9

Comment: That's the ***exact opposite*** of what you said you wanted in your question. Perhaps what you need is to not be drawing overlapping squares but convert the finger strokes into a "thick line" (composed of triangles). You would draw those triangles with blending but they wouldn't overlap each other except when the path actually crosses back over itself.